# Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?

Tags: windows-7

There's a folder on my desktop called like 'example' and when I try to delete it it says "You require permission from the computer's admistrator to make changes to this folder" when checking the properties; the Current owner says "Unable to display current owner."

I have tried many solutions found online, including enabling & signing into the adminstrator account, but haven't been able to fix it. My situation is extremely similar [to this](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/118340-folder-access-denied-unable-display-current-owner.html).

I can't even open the folder. I am running Windows 7 x64 Home Premium. I can't do anything to the folder because I need permission from my 'computer administrator' It's extremely weird, and I can't fix it. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Yes, I'm adminsitrator on my computer.

Comment: If you go to computer management (right-click on "My Computer" and select "Manage"), then "Shared Folders," and then "Open Files" ... is the file/folder listed there as Open?

Comment: This is more than likely not an issue of Admin privileges. I would put money on this folder being used by an application or malware. Try booting into safe mode (F8 on boot) and deleting the folder.

Comment: you can also try LongPathTool. its for deleting files,folder,pictures and etc. that "can't be deleted" :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) on the folder.

Answer (score 27):

Reset the properties of the folder.

Start menu → All Programs → Accessories → Right click on Command Prompt → Run As Administrator.

The type the following

```
cd\path\to\location\of\the\folder
takeown /r /d y /f example
icacls example /reset /t /c /q
```

Comment: This works great.  I made a batch file containing the two commands, replacing "example" with "%1" in the batch file.

Comment: This worked great for me too when copying data from a HDD from an old XP machine. Bear in mind the top path is the parent directory for the folder you wish to change the properties of, in my scenario `O:\Documents and Settings` with `example` being the user directory name.

Comment: To finish things off: the command for deleting the folder and everything below it is: `rmdir /S /Q example`

Answer (score 2):

[Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) has helped me delete almost every stubborn file/folder I've come across. Perhaps you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

How about booting from some Linux Live CD and then deleting the folder from Linux?
You can also use Volkov Commander, it should delete the folder...

http://vvv.kiev.ua/download/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue but in my situation it was not fixed by changing permissions.
I tried what Sathya suggested using the administrator account, but I kept getting "Access denied" messages.

Then I found out that I had an open Cygwin terminal on that specific folder. As soon as I 'cd' out of that folder I was able to delete the folder in question without problem.

For some reason, the message I was getting when trying to delete the folder was not "Another application is accessing the folder", but a misguiding "You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder".

Comment: This happened to me too. I was building something and Cywgin wouldn't let go. In the build process, there was a `ls` running somewhere that never completed. As soon as I killed the `ls` and the window that started up the build, the folder was no longer wacko.