# Unable to gain permission to directory on disk

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator)

Here´s the deal:

I have a folder, it´s the folder of one of my smaller projects and it used to contain a couple of images. Just a couple of minutes ago I was commiting the images to my git repo (since I was finished for the day with them), but suddenly when I press commit I get this strange error:

```
    Access is denied
```

The strangest thing of it all is that I have *one* account (the ***default*** administrators account). I have tried all these things:

1. Changing the permissions of the folder
2. Deleting it with the shell
3. Deleting it through an elevated command prompt
   (I even tried setting the folder as a symlink directory junction to NUL, but alas, nothing but the aforementioned error)
4. Logout/in and restarting my shell/computer

But to no avail, whatever I try to do, throws me that blasted error (either as plain text or as an actual window). Although it contains nothing, it´s still sitting there, alive and well.

So, what are my options (apart from actually formatting the drive)?

Note that I don´t care about recovering the contents of the folder, it just annoys me that I can´t gain permissions to open it!