# Deleting a folder in windows 7: Permission denied

Tags: windows-7, permissions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator)
>   [Unable to delete folder in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/321468/unable-to-delete-folder-in-windows-7)

I've got an old backup folder I need to delete (I know this happens a lot) and once again I'm getting the "you need permission" dialog and can't remove a couple of the folders. I've tried everything I know to get permissions, but nothing's worked.
So far every user on the system (Everyone, implicitly and explicitly) has Full Control, and I also tried changing the ownership of the file (even though I'm logged in as an admin) to my personal account, the admin account, and finally to "Everyone." No changes, aside from being told I need permission from *myself* and from *Everyone* respectively.

Are there some steps I missed? Deleting the folder from cmd didn't work either, even in an admin session. Checked the other questions on here for system permissions windows 7, no luck. I can't believe Win 7 has such bad issues with permissions. Also tried `TakeOwn /F folder /R /A`, no luck.

Comment: Did you try rebooting, and then trying to delete it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator) and/or [Unable to delete folder in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/321468/unable-to-delete-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: @techie007 It's been rebooted, the folder's been here for a month. It's not a duplicate as I've followed all advice in the other questions, nothing  thus far has corrected this issue including those two.

Comment: Have you tried with Unlocker in second link?

Comment: Have you run a disk check (chkdsk) to ensure there's no file corruption?    Also check out [How do I delete a 'locked' file?](http://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file) specifically [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/13291/how-do-i-delete-a-locked-file/13303#13303) about Process Explorer. Perhaps provide a specific list of what you've tried?

Comment: Unlocker DID work surprisingly, even though no processes were using it. Thanks!