# Can't remove Windows 8 user account files to free up space

Tags: windows-8, permissions, user-accounts, file-permissions

So when I was installing Windows 8 Pro (which came as an upgrade from a previous version of Windows) I created an account. Let's call it "DC". During the upgrade Windows used up quite a lot of space for that account: about 25 GB.

Now when Windows 8 is installed I went into the Control Panel / Users and removed the "DC" account. I also made sure to check the box to remove all of its files.

But when I go the "C:\Users\DC" folder on the hard drive, I see that the DC files are still there:

[image]

If I do its properties it shows that it still takes 25 GB of space, that I want to reclaim. (I have a 256 GB SSD, so as you see I can't waste that much space!)

I log in as a built-in administrator and try to delete those files (by deleting the "C:\Users\DC" folder in Windows Explorer.) After a quick investigation it turns out that the most of the space is used up by the "Windows.old" file. But no matter what I do, it always results in this window:

[image]

I tried booting in a safe mode and it still gave me the same error.

Any idea how to remove that "C:\Users\DC" folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7) and/or [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator)

Comment: @techie007: Thank you. That solved it.