# I took ownership of a external USB drive folder using takeown/icacls command (now it shows my computer name inthe owner), how do I revert it?

Tags: windows-10, usb, permissions, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I used takeown/icacls using post at [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator)

I now want to revert permissions to the original USB drive ownership. How can I do that?

Comment: do you have access to the machine that owned it?

Comment: @Keltari yes, have access to machine.